# html to xhtml conversion in java

Tags: java

how can we convert html to well formed xhtml by using Http class api,if possible please give a
demonstration code....thanks

Comment: What is the "Http class api"?

Comment: @skaffman Perhaps [`java.net`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) or the like.

Answer (score 14):

I just did it using Jsoup, if it works for you:

```
private String htmlToXhtml(final String html) {
    final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
    return document.html();
}
```

Some useful content where my solution came from:

- [Is it possible to convert HTML into XHTML with Jsoup 1.8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087077/is-it-possible-to-convert-html-into-xhtml-with-jsoup-1-8-1)
- http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-do-html-xml-conversion-generate-closed-tags

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at J-Tidy: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/  It usually does a quite good job cleaning up messy html and converting it to xhtml.

Comment: See examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063870/jtidy-java-api-toconvert-html-to-xhtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get xhtml from html

```
public static String getXHTMLFromHTML(String inputFile,
            String outputFile) throws Exception {

        File file = new File(inputFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); 
            tidy.setXHTML(true); 
            tidy.parse(is, fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(fos != null){
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    fos = null;
                }
                fos = null;
            }
            if(is != null){
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    is = null;
                }
                is = null;
            }
        }

        return outputFile;
    }
```

Comment: If you declare `outputFile` as parameter you don't have to `return` it in addition. Java's parameter passing is by-value and for reference types, like `String`, this value is the reference to the object (on the heap) created, and passed, by the caller. That means, changes to it inside the function are also visible to the caller once the function has ended. (Apart from inventing this wheel again when libraries exist that do that for us; see the other answers.)