# JTidy java API toConvert HTML to XHTML

Tags: java, html, xhtml, jtidy

I am using JTidy to convert from HTML to XHTML but I found in my XHTML file this tag `&nbsp;`. 
Can i prevent it ?
this is my code

```
    //from html to xhtml
   try   
    {  
        fis = new FileInputStream(htmlFileName);  
    }  
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e)   
    {  
        System.out.println("File not found: " + htmlFileName);  
    }  
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); 
        tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
        tidy.setXmlTags(false);
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setXHTML(true);// 
        tidy.setMakeClean(true);
        Document xmlDoc = tidy.parseDOM(fis, null);  
    try  
    {  
        tidy.pprint(xmlDoc,new FileOutputStream("c.xhtml"));  
    }  
    catch(Exception e)  
    {  
    }
```

Comment: Which version of jtidy are u using and how are you calling it?

Comment: @Waxolunist  thank you i, edited the question so u can see my code

Comment: take care with .setMakeClean, as it may cause <div> and <span> tags to be merged, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a function that parse the the xhtml code and remove the unwelcome tags
and to add a link to the css File "tableStyle.css"

```
    public static  String xhtmlparser(){ 
    String Cleanline="";

    try { 
        // the file url
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c.xhtml");
        // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine = null;
        int linescounter=0;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {// read every line in the file             
            String m=strLine.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "");
            linescounter++;
            if(linescounter==5)
                m=m+"\n"+ "<link rel="+ "\"stylesheet\" "+"type="+ "\"text/css\" "+"href= " +"\"tableStyle.css\""+ "/>";
            Cleanline+=m+"\n";
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){}

    return Cleanline;
}
```

but as a performance issue is it good?

by the way it works will

Comment: Shouldn't the &nbsp; entities be converted to &#160;?

Answer (score 6):

I had only success, when the input is treated as XML as well. So either set xmltags to true

```
 tidy.setXmlTags(true);
```

and live with the errors and warnings or do the conversion twice.
First conversion to sanitize the html (html to xhtml) and a second conversion from xhtml to xhtml with set xmltags, thus no errors and warnings occur.

```
        String htmlFileName = "test.html";
    try( InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(htmlFileName);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("tmp.xhtml");) {
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setShowWarnings(true);
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setXHTML(true);
        tidy.setMakeClean(true);
        Document xmlDoc = tidy.parseDOM(in, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try( InputStream in = new FileInputStream("tmp.xhtml");
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c.xhtml");) {
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setShowWarnings(true);
        tidy.setXmlTags(true);
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setXHTML(true);
        tidy.setMakeClean(true);
        Document xmlDoc = tidy.parseDOM(in, null);
        tidy.pprint(xmlDoc, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I used the latest jtidy version 938.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get xhtml from html

```
public static String getXHTMLFromHTML(String inputFile,
            String outputFile) throws Exception {

        File file = new File(inputFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); 
            tidy.setXHTML(true); 
            tidy.parse(is, fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(fos != null){
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    fos = null;
                }
                fos = null;
            }
            if(is != null){
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    is = null;
                }
                is = null;
            }
        }

        return outputFile;
    }
```