# Create the mhtml file using java

Tags: java, jtidy, mhtml

Can any one please suggest how to create an `mhtml` file using Java? I have already used the `jtidy` API (sourceforge), but I am unable to open the page in a browser. I am getting a blank screen if I open the mhtml file in IE.

Note : File (.mhtml) created successfully, but not open in IE 8)
( Please refer the below link)
[JTidy java API toConvert HTML to XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063870/jtidy-java-api-toconvert-html-to-xhtml?rq=1)

Comment: Please refer the below link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063870/jtidy-java-api-toconvert-html-to-xhtml?rq=1 (  i could not able to open the output .mhtml file in IE 8)