# Is it possible to convert HTML into XHTML with Jsoup 1.8.1?

Tags: java, html, xhtml, jsoup

```
String body = "<br>";
Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(body);
document.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
String str = document.body().html();
System.out.println(str);
```

expect: `<br />`

result: `<br>`

Can Jsoup convert value HTML into XHTML?

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me. I tested it using `1.7.2` version.

Comment: Not working for me, I'm using `1.8.1`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

See [`Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.html):

```
private String toXHTML( String html ) {
    final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);    
    return document.html();
}
```

Comment: You most likely also want to:  `document.outputSettings().escapeMode(org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml)` to convert `&nbsp;` to `&#xa0;` — the former isn't allowed in xhtml.

Answer (score 7):

You should tell that syntax you want to leave the string in HTML or XML.

```
public String parserXHtml(String html) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
        document.outputSettings().syntax(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml); //This will ensure the validity
        document.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");
        return document.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use JTidy API to do this. Use jtidy-r938.jar

You can use the following method to get xhtml from html

```
public static String getXHTMLFromHTML(String inputFile,
            String outputFile) throws Exception {

        File file = new File(inputFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); 
            tidy.setXHTML(true); 
            tidy.parse(is, fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(fos != null){
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    fos = null;
                }
                fos = null;
            }
            if(is != null){
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    is = null;
                }
                is = null;
            }
        }

        return outputFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String htmlToXhtml(String htmlContent) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);
    doc = Jsoup.parse(doc.html(),Parser.xmlParser());
    String xhtml = doc.html();
    return xhtml;
}
```