# How to convert xhtml to html in java?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, xhtml, jsoup

I converted an html string to xhtml in java using jsoup as shown here: [Is it possible to convert HTML into XHTML with Jsoup 1.8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087077/is-it-possible-to-convert-html-into-xhtml-with-jsoup-1-8-1)

However, I couldn't find a way to do the opposite, I mean, convert xhtml to html; is there a way to do this in java?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.html` instead of `Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml` you can use the example code from [that stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087077/is-it-possible-to-convert-html-into-xhtml-with-jsoup-1-8-1) to convert xhtml back to html.

#### Code example:

```
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.EscapeMode;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String body = "<br>";
    Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(body);
    document.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
    String str = document.body().html();
    System.out.println("XHTML:\n"+toXHTML(str));
    System.out.println("\nHTML:\n"+toHTML(str));
    }
    
    static String toHTML( String html ) {
    final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.html);    
    return document.html();
}
    static String toXHTML( String html ) {
    final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    document.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);    
    return document.html();
}
}
```

#### Output:

```
XHTML:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <br />
 </body>
</html>

HTML:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <br>
 </body>
</html>
```

References:
[Is it possible to convert HTML into XHTML with Jsoup 1.8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087077/is-it-possible-to-convert-html-into-xhtml-with-jsoup-1-8-1) - Henry
[Jsoup document settings](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.html)